# Implementing Smooth Scroll?

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-gridview, android-scrollview

I am newbie to Android. I need to implement smooth scroll like iPhone in android. I have tried using

> smoothScrollBy(x,y)

But it is not giving me what i expected. Can anyone suggest me some solutions. Smooth Scroll should be applicable for both

- `ListView`
- `ScrollView`

Am struggling for more than a week.

Comment: Perhaps tell us what you expected and what smoothScrollby is actually doing so e can help.

Comment: smoothScroolBy(int dx,int dy) is used to scroll to the position smoothly instead of immediately.

I need to scroll my listview and scrollview like iPhone scrolling in which if it reaches last item  of listview it will add extra 20px at the end of the listview.It made us to feel like a smooth scroll  but in android a blue shade appears and it is very hard to scroll.